# Is there a way to use this.onClick event and still be able to use "this" in function it calls?

Tags: javascript, html

project with these needs.
(10 points) When a button is clicked, the appropriate points are added to the total score.
(10 points) You are Not allowed to make any change to the HTML code provided above. In other words, you need to write unobtrusive JavaScript code, attaching event handlers in JavaScript rather than in HTML.
(10 points) The window.onload event handler should be an anonymous function.
(10 points) You should use the same event handler to handle the onclick event occurred on all of the four buttons on the webpage. In other words, you need to avoid code redundancy by using the this keyword.

I would like if someone could tell me a way I can use "this" in both of my functions so it doesn't have to be repetative like it is now in the first function, something like what I commented out. Or a way to simplify the code so it works as it does now.

```
    <script>
window.onload = pageLoad();
function pageLoad() {
    //this.onclick = okClick;
    document.getElementById("6pt").onclick = okClick;
    document.getElementById("3pt").onclick = okClick;
    document.getElementById("2pt").onclick = okClick;
    document.getElementById("1pt").onclick = okClick;
}
function okClick() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("score").value;
    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    var num2 = num1 + parseInt(this.id[0]);
    document.getElementById("score").value = num2;

}
</script>
    <body>
    <div>
        <input id="score" type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="6pt">6 points (touchdown)</button>
        <button id="3pt">3 points (field goal)</button>
        <button id="2pt">2 points (safety/2-point conversion)</button>
        <button id="1pt">1 point (extra point)</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you write the code that you tried and did not work? I can't understand what you are asking about exactly but it seems like you are having scope issues.

Comment: In the "okClick" function, because it is an event handler, "this" will refer to the element triggering the event. For the "onLoad" the Window object is the element calling the event, assigning "window" to "this" in that scope. What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: See Sidd's answer below to possibly address what you're looking for. Also, your window.onload is executing the function and binding the result "nothing" to the onload event. Remove the paren. See my comment on Sidd.

Comment: @RamyNasr the code I tried and did not work would be the commented out part instead of the document.get... for each button it will work but then I won't be able to use the ("this.id[0]") in the onClick() function to get the value i need to add to the score attribute.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers, like `onclick` are called in the context of the target object, thus you can safely use `this` within any event handler function. This also applies to jQuery attached events.

The above is valid for the 'okClick' function. You asked about "both of my functions", so if you're referring to `pageLoad`, that function is not executed in the context of an object, so you can't use `this`. But why would you need it? It won't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give all those elements a class, and then use

```
var myLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
for(var i=0;i<myLinks.length;i++)
    myLinks[i].onclick = okClick;
```

Inside okClick, the clicked element will be available via `this` (and also `event.target`).

Comment: Here is an example of what Sidd is saying with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/qyqy6bcv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function which will give a given context to your function:

```
var context = window;
context.something = 5;

var myFunc = function () {

    console.log(this.something); //5

}.bind(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is attach the same `okClick()` to each button then you should try and use a more general selector than ID. You can only have one ID per element so, like you've noticed, you must individually hook into each one.

Instead, try a more general selector, like `document.getElementsByClassName("className");`, which would be a bit more general:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="score" type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="6pt" class="score-button">6 points (touchdown)</button>
        <button id="3pt" class="score-button">3 points (field goal)</button>
        <button id="2pt" class="score-button">2 points (safety/2-point conversion)</button>
        <button id="1pt" class="score-button">1 point (extra point)</button>
    </div>

<script>
    (function(){
         // Same as yours
         function okClick() { ... }

         var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("score-button");
         for(var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++)
         {
             buttons[i].onClick = okClick;
         }
    }).call(this);
</script>
</body>
```

There's fancier selectors available in either `jQuery` or more modern `javascript` implementations which will save you having to use a class selector, you'll have to read into that though - or see Sidd's answer, which is doing exactly that (it's cleaner).

Comment: The problem here is that "this" in the scope above, being called by the anonymous function, will be the window.

Comment: That's just a force of habit for the functions scope, you'd get the same out of a `()`. I write it like that incase the code gets dumped into other scopes for some reason or another. The question's request to use `this` to reduce the LOC's in his first function likely stems from using it to attach to the button without a bunch of `document.getElementById(...);`